# Llamar a una función al seleccionar un día de un input de tipo date (Django)

Tags: html, python, django

buenos días a todos. Estoy haciendo una web con un sistema de reservas y necesito llamar desde el HTML a una función en concreto cuando el usuario selecciona un día. Es decir, el usuario selecciona un día, y en cuanto selecciona el día, se llama a la función que comprueba qué horas están disponibles para ese día.

La función funciona, pero no sé cómo llamarla desde el HTML. He probado con onchange, pero no me vale, porque envía el formulario entero y llama a la función que registra la cita, es decir, funciona como si hiciese click en el botón de enviar.

Coloco el código "relevante":

El HTML con el input que debería de llamar a una función en concreto y el botón que envía el formulario y se registra la cita:

```
<form>
    <input type="date" name="a_day">
    <button type="submit" name="send">Solicitar cita</button>
</form>
```

Y bueno, el código de la función no creo que sea relevante, lo único que necesito es llamar a esa función cuando el usuario selecciona un día del calendario.

Un saludo y muchísimas gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 3):

yo creo que eso lo puedes solucionar facil con una función ajax, le pasas como datos el valor del input date y con script php en el que proceses la fecha y hagas la búsqueda te dará las horas disponibles sin tener que recargar la página,no estoy para que la llamada funcione cuando seleccionas la fecha prueba con esto

```
<input type="date" id="fecha"/>
```

```
$(function(){
    $("#fecha").change(function(){
        var valor = $(this).val();
        if(valor!=""){
            //llamada a la funcion
        } else {
            //pass
        }
    })
})
```